.NET Aspire vs Azure Application Insights
.NET Aspire gives us traces and metrics. But Azure Application Insights also has traces and metrics. So where is an advantage of .Net Aspire?
Traces and metrics of .NET Aspire are intended to use on localhost and traces and metrics of Application Insights are intended to use on production?

Aspire is a framework for orchestration of cloud native applications. It uses OpenTelemetry to provide traces and metrics to the dashboard.
Application Insights is a destination for traces and metrics.  OpenTelemetry is one way to send them to Application Insights.
In production, one wouldn't use the Aspire dashboard for traces and metrics, but would rather send them to a service like Application Insights.
So, the Aspire Dashboard provides some of the services of Application Insights, but is meant to be a development tool.  Aspire provides many other features not related to Telemetry, traces, or metrics.
